# Why does the google search field show arrows when a word is misspelled?

Tags: desktop, google-search

When typing a misspelled word on https://www.google.com/ the word is underlined in red but also arrows appear to the right of it like so:

[image]

Why are these arrows [image] there? This is happening across multiple browsers on desktop.

Zooming in revealed that it is actually a vertical scrollbar that is applied:
[image]

Comment: No repro. Please add more details, like the name and version of the operative system and web browser you are using, the URL shown on the results page, if you have signed in to one or multiple accounts, etc.  Also, mention if you can reproduce this in private/incognito navigation mode with all the extensions disabled.

Comment: @Wicket, strangely enough, I am no longer able to reproduce it as well . Perhaps it was a bug that is now fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. There might be a lot of things that might cause that. I'm not sure if ["forensics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_forensics) is something that could be done here and if it is worth going into it for a "no victims" case. Anyway, for issues like this, I prefer to refer to them as a [glitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch#Computer_glitch) and leave the post here as an anecdotal log entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To indicate that pressing the down arrow will cycle you through the suggested search terms, with the correct spelling applied.